# how to insert file name into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I'm trying to figure out from a long time to print my file name in the MySQL database, file is uploading successfully into the path folder but unable to insert the file name into the database. below is my code

```
Choose file: <span class="text-danger">Max size 1mb, doc, pdf, jpg, jpeg, png & gif only</span>
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" required> 
            <input type="hidden" value="Upload Image" name="submit">

     <?php
 $target_dir = "../online/upload_files/";
 $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
 $uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo '<span style="color:#C0392B;text-align:center; size:45"> Sorry, 
 file already exists.</span>';
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

 // Check file size
 if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 1048576) {
echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
$uploadOk = 0;
 }

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != 
"jpeg"
 && $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "doc" && $imageFileType != 
"docx" 
&& $imageFileType != "pdf"&& $imageFileType != "xlsx") {
   echo  '<span style="color:#C0392B;text-align:center;">Sorry, only JPG, 
 JPEG, PNG, doc, pdf & GIF  files are allowed.</span>' ;
    $uploadOk = 0;
 }

 // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
 if ($uploadOk == 0) {
     echo '<span style="color:#C0392B;text-align:center;">Sorry, your file 
 was not uploaded.</span>';

 // if everything is ok, try to upload file
  } else {
     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], 
 $target_file)) {
         echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has 
 been uploaded. & <b>Proposal Submited Successfully.</b>";
     } else {
         echo '<span style="color:#C0392B;text-align:center;"> Sorry, there 
 was an error uploading your file.</span>';
     }
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add Following Code

```
$filename= $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$query = INSERT INTO `table`(`image`) VALUES ("$filename");
```

Comment: this should be like thi : ("$filename") ;P